# Prevent unnecessary method execution

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Element class which looks simplified like this:

```
public class Element
{
    public Point Position { get; set; }

    public delegate void GeometryChangedEventHandler();
    public event GeometryChangedEventHandler GeometryChanged;

    public void Move()
    {
        //...
    }
    public void FinalMove()
    {
        GeometryChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

The UIElements position is bound to the Position property. Then I have
a further class which is dependent to the position of two Elements.
If the Elements GeometryChanged, then it should call UpdateGeometry()

```
public class DependentElement
{
    public Element Element1 { get; }
    public Element Element2 { get; }

    public Point Pos { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public DependentElement(Element Element1, Element Element2)
    {
        this.Element1 = Element1;
        this.Element2 = Element2;

        Element1.GeometryChanged += UpdateGeometry;
        Element2.GeometryChanged += UpdateGeometry;
    }

    private void UpdateGeometry()
    {
        //Update Pos, Width and Height
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the Elements can moved individually or together. When
moving the elements together it would invoke the event twice, which is not
necessary. Is there any technique to prevent this - something like the RoutedEventArgs where
I can set e.Handled to true.

A workaround would be to inject the class which allows me to move multiple elements and create a custom event for that operation. But I think it wouldn't be a nice solution.

Comment: This might be a case of premature optimization.  Are you truly seeing a performance hit in the multiple-element case?

Comment: I've another element which takes in practice up to 30 element references. In this case that would be 29 unnecessary method calls. It should still going fast but when I've 20 of these elements and I would move all dependent elements in the same operation, it would be 580 calls to much. Maybe a new event MultipleElementsMoved isn't as bad as I thought it would be